# Echo each image in an array

Tags: php, json, wikipedia

im using the Wikipedia API to get images and a description for my site, and I need your help with the images. Currently I'm using this:

```
$wurl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info|images&titles=".$wsearch."&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids&exintro";

$wjson = file_get_contents($wurl);
$wdata = json_decode($wjson);
$wpageid = $wdata->query->pageids['0'];
if ($wpageid == -1)
{
}
else
{
echo"
<div id='images'>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<p style='padding-bottom:8px;border-bottom: 6px solid #333;width:100%;'>Images for <b>$search</b>:</br></p>
<div class='resultbox random-color-".rand(1,3)."'>
";

foreach($wdata->query->pages->$wpageid->images as $iimages)
{
$ititle = $iimages->title;
$iname = $ititle;   
$ifilename = str_replace(" ", "_",$iname);
$idigest = md5($ifilename);
$ifolder = $idigest[0] . '/' . $idigest[0] . $idigest[1] . '/' .  urlencode($iname);
$iurl = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/' . $ifolder;
echo"
<img style='height:100px;' src='$irurl'>
";
}
echo"
</div>
</div>
";
}
```

To echo each individual image from the url:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info|images&titles=google&format=json&explaintext&redirects&inprop=url&indexpageids&exintro

However, I can't get anything back, or at least nothing is displaying on my page. I'm very new to JSON, so can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I hope you can tell me and future viewers to do it, because its really annoying... lol, anyway thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
<div class="resultbox random-color-3">
<img src'http:="" upload.wikimedia.org="" wikipedia="" commons="" 4="" 4a="" commons-logo.svg'=""/>
<img src'http:="" upload.wikimedia.org="" wikipedia="" commons="" f="" fe="" crystal_clear_app_browser.png'=""/>
<img src'http:="" upload.wikimedia.org="" wikipedia="" commons="" e="" e5="" eric_schmidt_at_the_37th_g8_summit_in_deauville_037.jpg'=""/>
<img src'http:="" upload.wikimedia.org="" wikipedia="" commons="" b="" b6="" factory_1b.svg'=""/>
<img src'http:="" upload.wikimedia.org="" wikipedia="" commons="" a="" a4="" flag_of_the_united_states.svg'=""/>
<img src'http:="" upload.wikimedia.org="" wikipedia="" commons="" 2="" 20="" google-logo.svg'=""/>
<img src'http:="" upload.wikimedia.org="" wikipedia="" commons="" b="" b7="" google1998.png'=""/>
<img src'http:="" upload.wikimedia.org="" wikipedia="" commons="" 6="" 69="" google_appliance.jpg'=""/>
<img src'http:="" upload.wikimedia.org="" wikipedia="" commons="" 5="" 54="" google_mountain_view_campus_dinosaur_skeleton_%27stan%27.jpg'=""/>
<img src'http:="" upload.wikimedia.org="" wikipedia="" commons="" 8="" 8c="" google_mountain_view_campus_garden.jpg'=""/>
</div>
```

it seems to be removing all the /'s and not replacing the spaces with underscores... any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570032/getting-wikipedia-infobox-content-with-jquery

Comment: thanks but thats in jquery, not php

Comment: Ive got your answer below....  Hope it works....its working great on my side....so I assume it will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error I can see in your code...

```
  $iurl = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/' . $ifolder;
  echo"<img style='height:100px;' src='$irurl'>";
```

Here you have `$iurl` but then youre calling `$irurl` in the src of the iamge...that could just be a typo on StackOverflow though.....

But thats not your real problem.  Your problem is that the wikipedia url takes the image, without the `File:` prepend, so you have to remove it.

This should work for you...

```
foreach($wdata->query->pages->$wpageid->images as $iimages)
{
$name = $iimages->title;
$filename = str_replace(' ', '_',$name);
$filename = str_replace("File:","",$filename);
$digest = md5($filename);
$folder = $digest[0].'/'.$digest[0].$digest[1].'/'.urlencode($filename);
$url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/'.$folder;

echo "<img src='$url'">;
}
```

Comment: forget my edit, you made some syntax errors, like me, they have been resolved, thanks!